# Recurring Build Issues with Turborepo: Forced Flags and 'dist' Folder File Deletion

Tags: monorepo, turborepo

I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently developing a UI and hooks library using React, managed with Turborepo. Initially, the development process was smooth, but I've encountered a couple of issues that recur:

Forced Flag Usage: For every development script execution, I need to use --force and --no-cache flags. This workaround usually resolves the issue, but it often requires multiple attempts for success.

'dist' Folder File Deletion: When running the development script, it initially works as expected, but eventually, all files within the 'dist' directory are deleted. This issue is critical as my project includes building four interdependent core packages in this order: 'icon', 'utils', 'hooks', and 'core' (the latter relying on all the previous ones). The removal of these files disrupts the dependency chain and complicates the build process.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions for these challenges. Your contributions, in the form of direct assistance or guidance on troubleshooting these issues, would be invaluable. Thank you in advance for your support and willingness to help.

Here is the repository URL for reference: https://github.com/HamzaAmar/pillar-ui/tree/develop.

Thank you so much.

this the **turbo.json** config

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "outputs": ["dist/**", "storybook-static/**", ".next/**", "!.next/cache/**"]
    },
    "test": {
      "outputs": ["coverage/**"],
      "dependsOn": ["^test"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "type:check": {
      "cache": false
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false,
      "persistent": false,
      "dependsOn": ["^build"]
    },
    "clean": {
      "cache": false
    }
  }
}
```

this what I want to happen

- **Core Package**: Acts as the central hub, integrating `utils`, `hooks`, and `icons` to provide a wide range of features and utilities.
- **Hooks Package**: Offers custom React hooks for enhanced component logic, relying exclusively on the `utils` package for consistent and reliable functionalities.
- **Utils Package**: The independent backbone providing essential utility functions, designed to be used throughout the project without any dependencies.
- **Icons Package**: A standalone collection of icons available for use anywhere in the application, with no external dependencies.